# Does the unary operator really gets executed first?

Tags: java, operators, unary-operator

I have this question regarding priorities. Java states that this is the priority to work out operators (from high to low):

1. postfix unary opartors xyz++, xyz--
2. prefixunary opartors ++xyz, --xyz
3. typeconversion/casting
4. "* / %
5. "+ -
6. << >>
7. < <= > >=
8. ==, !=
9. &
10. exclusive
11. |
12. &&
13. ||
14. ?:
15. =, +=, -=, *=, /=, %=

Now, if you look at unary operators, they state that:

> In the unary postfixnotation , unary gets executed after the expression.

Meaning that if you have:

```
int a = 2;
int b = a++ * 3;
```

`int b` will be 6, cause a only gets +1 after the expression.

> in the unary prefixnotation, unary gets executed before the expression:

```
int a = 2;
int b = ++a * 3;
```

`int b` will be 9.

My question is, doesnt this mean that postfix unary operators should be at number 6 and prefix at number 1? What am I seeing wrong?

Comment: When it says *after the expression*, it means after the expression it is attached to. In this exemple, the expression is simply **a**.

Comment: In your exemple, `a++ * 3` is equivalent to `int b = a * 3; a = a + 1;`, while `++a * 3` is `a = a + 1; int b = a * 3;`

Comment: I think the word expression is just not a very good choice. Store the value of "a" in "b" then increments AND Increments "a" then store the new value of "a" in "b" would have been better choices and not so confusing. As Ladislus explained. Probably due to translation. English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "expression" that the unary operator is applied after the evaluation of is `a`, not any expression it might be part of.